# Editing the volume peaks of multiple audios at the same time

Tags: c++, c, programming, audio-editing, plug-in

I have an English to Spanish audio dubbing job.
Where I have to take the volume peaks of the English audio and duplicate them in the correlative Spanish audio.

I would like to do it automatically since I have to do it with hundreds of audios at the same time.

I was looking for a way to program a plugin or do it with C # but the only library that seems to help (NAudio) I have not managed to install it.

So, I come to ask for help because I don't know where to start or if there is already a tool that does it.

Thanks

Comment: is there a piece of software that you already use at work for doing this editing before you wanted to automate it? you might have some success looking for open source alternatives to that software. Being open source will mean that the software will likely be free and have its code available for you and others to lok at, making it more likely that someone may have already created a way to automate this task

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned creating a C# program to do this, you can achieve that using the [LEADTOOLS Multimedia SDK](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/engine/multimedia) (Disclaimer: I work for the SDK’s vendor).

The SDK contains audio processing filters that can be used during playback, recording or modifying existing audio/video files. In particular, the following 2 filters might be what you need:

- First insert the [LEAD Audio VU Meter
  Filter](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/v21/multimedia/filters/lead-audio-vu-meter-filter.html),
  which allows you to measure the audio power levels either in the
  source (reference) audio or the target (that needs to be modified).
  You can then calculate the amount by which to modify the audio level
  to match the target to the source.
- Then insert the [LEAD Audio Volume
  Filter](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/v21/multimedia/filters/lead-audio-volume-filter.html),
  which allows you to modify the target volume level based on your
  calculations from the previous step.

Depending on your goal (playback, recording, or re-encoding), you can use these audio filters with the [Play control](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/v21/dh/multimedia/to/directshow-playback.html), [Capture control](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/v21/dh/multimedia/to/directshow-capture.html), or [Convert control](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/v21/dh/multimedia/to/directshow-conversion.html), respectively.

The SDK has .NET controls as well as Windows objects compatible with C++ and other languages, for use in either 32-bit or 64-bit applications. If you would like to try it, there’s a free evaluation [here](https://www.leadtools.com/downloads).